# What is the name of the font used?

Tags: font-identification

Please help me find it, that would be great. I already tried WhatTheFont, but it didn't actually bring up the font I needed.

[image]

Thanks
chirag

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [Helevetica Neue UltraLight](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/):

[image: Screenshot]